# Add art cover in OGG audio file

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

My intention is to add a cover art in ogg file containing only audio without it being created as a video.

Output: ffrobe audio.ogg

```
Input #0, ogg, from 'audio.ogg':
  Duration: 00:03:26.60, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 385 kb/s
  Stream #0:0: Audio: vorbis, 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 320 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc59.12.100 libvorbis
      album           : CMG Clássicos Pop Rock Nacionais
      artist          : Lobão
      date            : 1988
      genre           : Clássico Pop Rock Nacional
      TKEY            : E m
      title           : Cuidado!
```

I use the command below, but the cover art is generated as video in the output file:

```
ffmpeg -i "audio.ogg" -i "Cover.jpg" -map 0:a -map 1:v -c:a libvorbis -b:a 320k -metadata:s:v title="Album cover" -metadata:s:v comment="Cover (front)" -disposition:v attached_pic "audio_video.ogg"
```

While the file is being generated, several lines of messages Non-monotonous DTS appear on the screen:

```
[ogg @ 000001ced2dafa00] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 8802752, current: 8802432; changing to 8802752. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[ogg @ 000001ced2dafa00] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 8802752, current: 8802560; changing to 8802752. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[ogg @ 000001ced2dafa00] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 8802752, current: 8802688; changing to 8802752. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[libvorbis @ 000001ced2db0a40] Queue input is backward in time
    Last message repeated 14 times
[libvorbis @ 000001ced2db0a40] Queue input is backward in timetrate=   0.3kbits/s speed=25.3x
    Last message repeated 1 times
frame=    1 fps=0.1 q=-0.0 Lsize=    9570kB time=00:03:26.59 bitrate= 379.5kbits/s speed=25.4x
video:15kB audio:9494kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:7kB muxing overhead: 0.638836%
```

At end, the file is generated but the artwork appears as a video stream in the file.

Output:  ffrobe audio_video.ogg

```
Input #0, ogg, from 'audio_video.ogg':
  Duration: 00:03:26.60, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 379 kb/s
  Stream #0:0: Audio: vorbis, 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 320 kb/s
    Metadata:
      artist          : Lobão
      album           : CMG Clássicos Pop Rock Nacionais
      genre           : Clássico Pop Rock Nacional
      title           : Cuidado!
      TKEY            : E m
      date            : 1988
      encoder         : Lavc59.21.100 libvorbis
  Stream #0:1: Video: theora, yuv420p, 1018x1023 [SAR 1:1 DAR 1018:1023], 25 tbr, 25 tbn
    Metadata:
      title           : Album cover
      comment         : Cover (front)
      encoder         : Lavc59.21.100 libtheora
```

How do I add the image without generating a video stream and without the Non-monotonous DTS message lines?

@mashuptwice I used the suggested command in the link, but it didn't work. see below:

```
ffmpeg -i "audio.ogg" -map 0 -c:a copy -c copy -metadata:s:a METADATA_BLOCK_PICTURE="$(base64 --wrap 0 Cover.jpg)" "audio_cover.ogg"
```

Output: command ffmpeg with METADATA_BLOCK

```
Input #0, ogg, from 'audio.ogg':
  Duration: 00:03:26.60, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 385 kb/s
  Stream #0:0: Audio: vorbis, 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 320 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc59.21.100 libvorbis
      album           : CMG Clássicos Pop Rock Nacionais
      genre           : Clássico Pop Rock Nacional
      title           : Cuidado!
      TKEY            : E m
      date            : 1988
      artist          : Lobão
Output #0, ogg, to 'audio_cover.ogg':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf59.17.102
  Stream #0:0: Audio: vorbis, 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 320 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc59.21.100 libvorbis
      album           : CMG Clássicos Pop Rock Nacionais
      genre           : Clássico Pop Rock Nacional
      title           : Cuidado!
      TKEY            : E m
      date            : 1988
      artist          : Lobão
      METADATA_BLOCK_PICTURE: $(base64 --wrap 0 Cover.jpg)
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
size=    9735kB time=00:03:26.59 bitrate= 386.0kbits/s speed=1.37e+03x
video:0kB audio:9677kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:4kB muxing overhead: 0.597793%
```

The art was added in the metadata??!!!, but it doesn't show up in any player when the song is played?!... I'm a Windows user. I said that because I don't know if any player from another system can play the image the way it was added, ok?

I used it too, a command to attach cover art in MKV files, but it seems that OGG doesn't accept this command, see below:

Using ffmpeg with -attach command:

```
ffmpeg -i "audio.ogg" -attach "cover.jpeg" -map 0 -c:a copy -c copy -metadata:s:t mimetype="image/jpeg" -metadata:s:t:0 filename="cover.jpeg" "audio_cover.ogg"
```

Output: error

```
Input #0, ogg, from 'audio.ogg':
  Duration: 00:03:26.60, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 385 kb/s
  Stream #0:0: Audio: vorbis, 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 320 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc59.21.100 libvorbis
      album           : CMG Clássicos Pop Rock Nacionais
      genre           : Clássico Pop Rock Nacional
      title           : Cuidado!
      TKEY            : E m
      date            : 1988
      artist          : Lobão
[ogg @ 00000164388afe40] Unsupported codec id in stream 1
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Invalid argument
Error initializing output stream 0:1 --
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  File cover.jpeg -> Stream #0:1
```

The ogg file does not support attaching the image. It tries to attach the cover art to the 0:1 stream, but it shows a codec error, in the MKV file this does not occur?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61344932/add-coverart-into-ogg-containing-an-opus-audio-stream-with-ffmpeg-without-re-enc

Answer (score 5):

The attempt using `-metadata:s:a METADATA_BLOCK_PICTURE=...` is the correct one, but the details are wrong.

The base64 encoded image data must be prefixed with a header in accordance with https://xiph.org/flac/format.html#metadata_block_picture

This is an example for such a header:

```
$> echo -en "\0\0\0\x03\0\0\0\x0aimage/jpeg\0\0\0\x08test.jpg\0\0\0\x08\0\0\0\x0e\0\0\0\x20\0\0\0\0\0\0\x05\xad" \
  > vorbis.head
$> hexdump -C vorbis.head 
00000000  00 00 00 03 00 00 00 0a  69 6d 61 67 65 2f 6a 70  |........image/jp|
00000010  65 67 00 00 00 08 74 65  73 74 2e 6a 70 67 00 00  |eg....test.jpg..|
00000020  00 08 00 00 00 0e 00 00  00 20 00 00 00 00 00 00  |......... ......|
00000030  05 ad                                             |..|
00000032
```

You have to adapt the header for you cover image, most notably width, height, bpp and raw size, which are 8x14@32, 1453 bytes (0x8, 0xe, 0x20, 0x05ad) here.

All relevant values are 4 bytes (32 bit) little-endian, i.e. for a width of 320 replace the "\0\0\0\x08" with "\0\0\x01\x40".

You can add the cover art with a comment like:

```
ffmpeg -i inpug.flac.ogg  -acodec copy -map 0:a -metadata:s:a METADATA_BLOCK_PICTURE="$(cat vorbis.head cover.jpg | base64 --wrap 0)" output.flag.ogg
```

The `$(cat ....)` only works on Linux or other Unixy systems, on Windows this won't work.

Comment: I tried this, but alas, the data block is too big for the command line. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
ffmpeg -i audio.ogg -i Cover.jpg -c:a copy -c:v mjpeg `
-disposition:v attached_pic audio_video.mp4
```

Note the output is MP4 instead of OGG. On my system, Windows Explorer doesn't
support cover art with OGG.

Comment: But that's exactly what I'm managing to do, some final tests are missing, but I've already managed to put the art in ogg, it doesn't look like in the file explorer, like the mp3, but it's being included in ogg without being as a video stream, which was what I didn't want. Explanation: when I put an art on ogg and open the music on vlc, the art would open on the screen as if the ogg file was a video, so the art would appear fixed on the screen while the music was playing. What I'm doing is putting the art without it appearing on the vlc screen as a video.